# Probabilty Distribution of M objects moving in circular grid with N positions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayes-theorem

I have the below problem and I need help in how to approach this problem:

A circular track has N positions labeled 0 through N−1. M agents start at position 0 through M−1 (inclusive). An agent can make a valid move by moving forward one position (or goes from N-1 to 0) if the position it is moving into is empty. At each turn, we only consider agent that have a valid move available and make one of the valid moves that you choose randomly with equal probability. 
After k rounds, we need to compute the average and standard deviation of the position of the agents.

Comment: How is it related to normal distribution or bayes theorem?

Comment: Is the motion of cars and agents somehow correlated?

Comment: @d.k.o.Thanks for pointing this out, I was reading about bayes theorem and figured since next state will be dependent on the previous one, bayes is somehow involved. What would you suggest should be the approach?

Comment: @user Yes, edited the questio